# Prevent redirect to default /Account/Login in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a new custom login screen and want to redirect to this page and
I am trying to prevent the app to redirect to /Account/Login in asp.net webform 4.5 using form authentication.

I've created my webform project like this

[image]

and add below code in web.config file

```
<location path="Views">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Below is the folder structure:

[image]

when I accessing pages which are in my Views folder it will redirect me here

```
/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FViews%2FSetupInventory
```

but I have created my own custom login page and I want to redirect the user to this page named  `Login.aspx` in my root directory and prevent all redirection towards default `/Account/Login`.

How can I achieve this in my web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this part to your web.config :

```
<system.web>  
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

As you can see above, the loginUrl is where you specify the location of your new login form.

Comment: This will redirect same to `http://localhost:51560/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FViews%2FSetupInventory`

Comment: Check this file : App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs, look for LoginPath and change it accordingly. I think this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the right url of login in :

```
<forms loginUrl="~/name.aspx"/>
```

Comment: I give the right name like `<forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" />` but it will redirect to the same default login URL like I describe in my question. Please review your code by creating the demo application like I mentioned above.

Comment: Kindly Just do it in your web.config file.

Comment: Dear I do it and it will redirecting to `http://localhost:51560/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FViews%2FSetupInventory`